# Set up a catch-all inside a location with fallback to index.php

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm struggling with nginx config. I have a `server` block where I want all requests to go to `index.php?tags=$uri`, unless `$uri` exists (like `index.php?a=b` or `/?a=b`).

I would expect:

```
try_files $uri index.php?tags=$uri;
```

but, no, that would be too simple. That doesn't work for `/?a=b`, which is apparently not found, so it directs to `index.php?tags=/`

Maybe if I explicitly include an `index`, which is reasonable:

```
index index.php;
```

Nope. No dice. Same exact result across the board.

Also nothing with `$args`, `$request_uri` or combinations. Also not it:

```
try_files $request_uri/index.php $request_uri index.php?tags=$request_uri; // now I'm just guessing
```

Apache somehow knew what I meant always. Why doesn't nginx? I'd like these redirects (without `redirect` or `if`):

```
/   => /index.php
/index.php   => /index.php
/index.php?a=b   => /index.php?a=b
/?a=b   => /index.php?a=b
/foo   => /index.php?tags=foo (or /index.php?tags=/foo)
/foo/bar   => /index.php?tags=foo/bar (or /index.php?tags=/foo/bar)
/foo?bar=yes   => /index.php?tags=/foo%3Fbar%3Dyes
```

I'd like the query string to be encoded when redirected, but not the path, but really that's not so important.

(I also don't understand the practical difference between $uri and $request_uri. They seem to be doing the same half the time. But that's for another day.)

Much thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am achieving the wished result with the following configuration snippet:

```
location = / {
    index index.php;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?tags=$request_uri;
}
```

`try_files` tries... files. When you seek `/` with it, you search for a file with the same name, it is not interpreted as 'find the index file'. `index` does that job. Hence you need to separate this special case from the default, fall-back location.

The best part is your last wish: the arguments won't even be encoded since they do not need to (only the first question mark of a URI is relevant as everything following is an argument anyway).

Mind the use of [`$request_uri`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) (which contains the requested URI, with arguments, but does not normalize/cleanse it) instead of the normalized [`$uri`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri) (which cleans up the URI and remove arguments). Thus you may end up with:

```
///foo?bar=yes => index.php?tags=///foo?bar=yes
```

If you mind about it, you may use [`$uri`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri) in combination with [`$args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args):

```
location = / {
    index index.php;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?tags=$uri?$args;
}
```

producing:

```
///foo?bar=yes => index.php?tags=/foo?bar=yes
```

Comment: The `location = /` did the trick. Why can't you combine that inside the `location /` block? Does the `=` mean it only matches the exact uri? Thanks so much. They say nginx is easy.

Comment: Everything is thoroughly explained in the [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) documentation that I suggest you read. Look at the different modifiers.